# How to Upgrade glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded, maven-glassfish-plugin, glassfish-webspace

I want to upgrade Glassfish without internet connection. But I have already downloaded the latest version.

I have done the following steps,
For eg. **galssfish-3.0** is the **older version** and **glassfish-3.1** is the **newer version**.

**Step: 1**
I just copied the **glassfish-3.0/glassfish/domains/domain1** and pasted in **glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains**

**Step: 2**
In **glassfish-3.1/bin** `./asadmin` i just give the command `asadmin> start-domain --upgrade`

then i checked the version **asadmin> version** the ouput was

`Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (build 12)

Command version executed successfully.`

Is this correct or I need to follow some other ways to achieve this? If wrong Please guide me the right way.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,

Gnik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Upgrade Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2437/abmbr.html#gktgx) you did it right.

There are some hints in this guide for the migration of deployed applications:

> Application archives (EAR files) and component archives (JAR, WAR, and
>   RAR files) that are deployed in the source server do not require any
>   modification to run on Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1. Components that
>   may have incompatibilities are deployed on GlassFish Server 3.1 with
>   the compatibility property set to v2 and will run without change on
>   GlassFish Server 3.1. You may, however, want to consider modifying the
>   applications to conform to Java EE 6 requirements.
>
> ...
>
> Applications and components that are deployed in the source server are
>   deployed on the target server during the upgrade. Applications that do
>   not deploy successfully on the target server must be deployed manually
>   on the target server by the user.
>
> If a domain contains information about a deployed application and the
>   installed application components do not agree with the configuration
>   information, the configuration is migrated unchanged, without any
>   attempt to reconfigure the incorrect configurations.

You should read through the guide carefully and check your deployed applications for any errors / exceptions during server startup or manual redeployment.

Some time ago I made an update as described in the update guide from 3.0 to 3.1.1 and cannot remember any bigger problems.